# Rails 3.2 sass error on application.css precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets

After upgrading to rails 3.2 I'm getting this error on `rake assets:precompile`

```
Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "html .fileinput..."
```

here is the trace: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1285319/

`application.css` is pretty much the default:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self 
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

obviously it doesn't like the comments in CSS, was there some change in SASS or Rails I haven't noticed?

here are the versions of sass:

```
sass (3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
```

Comment: can you paste your css file which contains `html .fileinput...` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean... the stylesheet is inserted `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>` standard way

Comment: Are there other files in `assets/stylesheets`? Rails can’t be objecting to comments in CSS, nothing has changed in that regard.

Comment: yeah, sure. there are quite a many of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was caused by this line in `jquery.fileupload-ui.css` (jQuery File Upload UI Plugin CSS 6.3)

```
/* Fix for IE 6: */
*html .fileinput-button {
  line-height: 22px;
  margin: 1px -3px 0 0;
}
```